# context.createConicGradient is not a function

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm new to canvas, I was learning from MDN's [Canvas tutorial's color gradient part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#a_createconicgradient_example), and when I wanted to run the `context.createConicGradient` browser throws error:

> Uncaught TypeError: context.createConicGradient is not a function

I even copied the same code from the tutorial, but it throws this error anyway. I thought that this method was removed or deprecated from JS, but I didn't find anything reliable.

Here is the code from the tutorial:

```
  var conicGrad1 = ctx.createConicGradient(2, 62, 75);
  conicGrad1.addColorStop(0, '#A7D30C');
  conicGrad1.addColorStop(1, '#fff');
```

Comment: Have you checked “Browser compatibility” in the MDN? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createConicGradient#browser_compatibility In the few browsers that _do_ support it, you need to enable it via flags/preferences first.

Comment: @CBroe oh no, so it's not supported? So there is no any other way to create a conic gradient with canvas?

Answer (score 2):

The method **createConicGradient()** is experimental and not yet available in most browsers.

Check below for browser compatibility:

https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_canvasrenderingcontext2d_createconicgradient

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createConicGradient#browser_compatibility

If you want to experiment, you can open in Firefox:

> about:config

Then enable the property below:

> canvas.createConicGradient.enabled

After that, your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one helpful polyfill you can use: https://github.com/parksben/create-conical-gradient

```js
import 'create-conical-gradient'; // If you use the npm package.

const canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const gradient = ctx.createConicalGradient(240, 135, -Math.PI, Math.PI);

gradient.addColorStop(0, '#f00');
gradient.addColorStop(0.2, '#00f');
gradient.addColorStop(0.4, '#0ff');
gradient.addColorStop(0.6, '#f0f');
gradient.addColorStop(0.8, '#ff0');
gradient.addColorStop(1, '#f00');

ctx.fillStyle = gradient.pattern;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```